# Repeating drawing isosceles triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

From the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713645/controlling-the-scaling-of-predefined-x-ray-of-a-head-top-drawings-using-def), I would like to add repeated circles, rectangles, and isosceles triangles.
I applied this code to draw the following figure, but I could not use `\foreach` to repeat drawing the isosceles triangles

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, positioning, calc, intersections, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing, decorations.markings, decorations.fractals, decorations.footprints, shapes, shapes.misc, shapes.symbols, shapes.geometric, patterns, backgrounds, shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, shadings}%for snake
%
% begin to set all frametitles to bold
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{series=\bfseries}
% end to set all frametitles to bold
%
 \definecolor{darkteal2}{rgb}{0.,0.9,0.8}
\definecolor{darkgreen1}{rgb}{0.,0.55,0.1}

%begin definition xraytube and headtop   % in headtop apply horizontal flip of ear to compare angles
\def\scl{.4}
\def\wda{1}%1.2
\def\wdb{2}
\def\wdc{4}

\def\xraytube
{%
\begin{scope}[scale=\scl, opacity=1, line width=.05cm, rounded corners=5pt, transform shape,overlay]
\draw[gray, bottom color=gray, top color=gray!25](-\wda,0) --++(-90:\wdc) --++(180:\wdb) --++(-90:\wdb) --++(0:\wdb) --++(0:\wda) --++(0:\wda)--++(0:\wdb)  --++(90:\wdb) --++(180:\wdb) --++(90:\wdc) -- cycle;
\draw[gray, top color=gray, bottom color=gray!40](0,-.25) ellipse (1. and 0.5);
\end{scope}
}%

\def\headtop
{%
\begin{scope}[scale=2*\scl, line width=.05cm, rounded corners=3pt, rotate=0, looseness=1.,overlay]
\node (o) at (0,0) {};
\node (or) at ([shift={(0.:4.)}]o.center) {};
\node (ot) at ([shift={(86.:1.)}]o.center) {};
\node (ort) at ([shift={(95.:1.)}]or.center) {};
\node (x) at ([shift={(56.5:3.6)}]o.center) {};
\node (xt) at ([shift={(90:.3)}]x.center) {};
\node (xl) at ([shift={(180:.34)}]x.center) {};
\node (xr) at ([shift={(0:.34)}]x.center) {};

\draw[brown, bottom color=brown!60!orange!25!white, top color=brown!60] (xl.center) to [out=40, in=-140] (xt.center) to [out=-40, in=140] (xr.center);

\draw[brown, right color=brown!60!orange!25!white, left color=brown!60] (o.center) to [out=-170, in=160] (ot.center);

\draw[brown, left color=brown!60!orange!25!white, right color=brown!60] (or.center) to [out=-10, in=20] (ort.center);

\draw[brown, inner color=brown!60!orange!25!white, outer color=brown!60] (o.center) arc (180:360:2) to[out=90,in=0] (x.center) to[out=180,in=90] (o.center) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
}%
%end definition xraytube and headtop
\def\trngl
{%
\begin{scope}[scale=2*\scl, line width=.05cm, rotate=0]
\draw[green!70!black,fill=green!70!black]  (90:.55) -- (210:.55) -- (330:.55) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
}%

\begin{document}
% begin frame
\begin{frame}[t]
 \frametitle {xray tube headtop}

\vspace {-.4cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\hskip 5.4cm
\draw[gray, top color=gray, bottom color=gray, middle color=gray!40] (0,0) rectangle +(5,-.2) node[midway]{.};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
\begin{scope}[yshift=-6.5cm, xshift=9.86cm]
\xraytube
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=-4.2cm, xshift=8.28cm]
\headtop
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace {-.56cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={snake, amplitude=.4mm, segment length=3mm, post length=4mm}]
\hskip 7.83cm
\draw<2->[decorate, darkteal2, -latex, line width=.05cm] (0,0) -- ++(90:5.8cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\vspace {-3.1cm}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.4, transform shape]
\hskip 6cm
\begin{scope}[yshift=0cm, xshift=0cm]
\draw<2->[line width=.06cm, red, dashed] (0,0)--++(0:8cm);
\foreach \x in {2,4,6} \draw<2->[line width=.06cm, red, fill=red] (\x,0) circle (.25cm);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=2cm, xshift=-.25cm]
\draw<2->[line width=.06cm, blue, dashed] (.25,0)--++(0:8cm);
\foreach \x in {2,4,6} \draw<2->[line width=.06cm, blue, fill=blue] (\x,-0.25) rectangle ++(0.5,0.5);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[yshift=4cm, xshift=-.25cm]
\draw<2->[line width=.06cm, green!60!black, dashed] (.25,0)--++(0:8cm);
\hskip .92cm<2-> \trngl
\hskip .8cm<2-> \trngl
\hskip .8cm<2-> \trngl
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame} 
% end frame
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can make 3 `pic`, named `triangle`, `rectangle`, `circle`, then use a `for` loop to put them at desired position. Check PGFmanual for their syntaxes. Simple enough?

Comment: @Black Mild Thank you very much for your tip.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following code to draw the triangle

```
\begin{scope}[yshift=4cm, xshift=-.25cm]
\draw[line width=.06cm, green!60!black, dashed] (.25,0)--++(0:8cm);
\foreach \x in {2,4,6} \draw[line width=.06cm, green!70!black, fill=green!70!black] (\x,0) --++ (60:.6) --+ (-60:.6)-- cycle;
\end{scope}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: @Werner♦ I would like to know why you did downvote my answer. This code solved the problem I was seeking its answer?

Comment: I didn't; it was formatted poorly, so I updated that. However, because of its length and formatting, it ended up in the Low Quality Post review queue, where it may have been downvoted. For future reference, limit your question content to things that are relevant - there's no need to set the example using [`beamer`](//ctan.org/pkg/beamer), nor include the `xraytube` and beam. Then, for the answer, complete the code by setting it in a complete, minimal example. Just some suggestions.

Comment: @Werner♦ Thank you for your reply. I intentionally included the words "x-ray tube and top head" in the title, to make it easier to find this post, for those who are searching for such drawings. I included the code to draw them in beamer, to help people in the medical field, to draw such objects for presentation purposes.